# Error, 'only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [int]'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following adopted code is just used for example purposes:

```
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014],
    'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
```

`df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])`

`value_list = ['Tina', 'Molly', 'Jason']`

```
df[df.name.isin(value_list)]
```

Here, it can be seen that a list (i.e., value_list) has been passed. If i don't want to pass a list and just want to pass an integer (i.e, 24 in the reports column to find its corresponding row), what would be the ideal way. I tried to do this, but it actually doesn't works:

```
df[df.reports.isin(24)]
```

The error comes as: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [int].

Also, how can i find the corresponding 'name' against reports 24, (i.e., Molly)

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory. Put 24 in a list when you pass it. `.isin([24])`. But then you probably want `==` if there's only one item.

Comment: Thanks @ roganjosh. 
Yes, you are right. I actually didn't wanted to pass the list, but == would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use boolean-indexing:

```
>>> df
             name  reports  year
Cochice     Jason        4  2012
Pima        Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa     Jake        2  2014
Yuma          Amy        3  2014
>>> df[df.reports == 24]
       name  reports  year
Pima  Molly       24  2012
```

You *could* use `.isin` with a single-element list:

```
>>> df[df.reports.isin([24])]
       name  reports  year
Pima  Molly       24  2012
```

But the boolean-indexing option is what you would typically see.

If you have a *large* data-frame (over 10,000 rows, let's say) and a more complex boolean-expression, you can do this efficiently with `df.query`:

```
>>> df.query("reports==24 or name == 'Jason'")
          name  reports  year
Cochice  Jason        4  2012
Pima     Molly       24  2012
```

And this will be fast and memory-efficient if you have the `numexpr` engine available.

Comment: Thanks @ juanpa.arrivillaga ... i am grateful. This df.query is a really nice thing to learn. Also, == instead of .isin worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @John use `df.query` with care, on small data-frames, it can actually make performance [*worse*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#pandas-eval-performance).

Comment: Thank you ... i would be careful :-)